# How to achieve multiple sticky headers and one scrollbar inside Angular 8 app nested components?

Tags: css, angular

How can we apply sticky headers inside nested components of an Angular app but with only one/main scroll bar?

Example of the app template layout would be:

```
                                 // main component / body
 <div class="app-container">
    
   <div class="header-0">   header text    </div>
   <div class="content-0">   some content   </div>

   <nested-component-1></nested-component-1>

 </div>

                                 // <nested-component-1> 
                                 // - 1st nested component inside of: main component
 <div class="container">
    
   <div class="header-1">   header text    </div>
   <div class="content-1">   some content   </div>

   <nested-component-2></nested-component-2>

 </div>

                                 // <nested-component-2> 
                                 // - 2nd nested component inside of: <nested-component-1>
 <div class="container">
    
   <div class="header-2">   header text    </div>
   <div class="content-2">   some content   </div>

   <nested-component-3></nested-component-3>

 </div>
                                 // etc.
```

I do not want each component to have a scroll bar - only the main one.
I want the headers of each nested sub-component 0, 1, 2 ... to stack up below one another and remain visible/sticky and let the content scroll up.

This is easy if all is within one template with CSS:

```
div.sticky {
    top: X;
    z-index: Y;
    position: fixed;
    position: sticky;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
}
```

However, the business logic of the content requires sub-components, which brakes this approach. How can this be resolved?

Comment: try to put your css in style.css in app folder where you index.html is located this will apply your css to all components